# Merge Rows and Views PDF integration

Tags: 7, entities, views

I've got a view that outputs a pdf business card for every student with all the classes he attends.
Someting like this:

```
2014
Name Surname
class1, class2, class3
```

To associate students and classes I use a Session content type with fields: year, entity referenced student and entity referenced class (Students and Classes are separated content types as well).

Because I need to control the exact position of every field on the final pdf, I use [views PDF](https://drupal.org/project/views_pdf).
To achieve that some kind of "GROUP_CONCAT" on classes I succesfully used [Merge Rows](https://drupal.org/project/views_merge_rows) module.

My query is ok. If I try it on page display everything is all right, but when I try to make a PDF display using [views PDF](https://drupal.org/project/views_pdf) it shows just one value, not the entire comma separated string of classes.
I've tried many combinations of merge rows settings, played with custom html output of fields, but **it seems that Merge Rows doesn't work on PDF display**.
Any idea to make this work?

As suggested for invoices in the paragraph "Append and Include other Views" from [views PDF documentation](https://drupal.org/node/1086584), I also tried to split the view into two separate views: the main and the secondary view of classes included as a field but with no success. The classes view doesn't filter content using the contextual filters passed by the main view. Removing contextual filter, I can see classes under student name, but all of them. And the query is really slow...

Another solution could be to rewrite the SQL using GROUP_CONCAT (I use MySQL)... But how?

What should I do?

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved applying [this patch](https://drupal.org/node/1362524#comment-8477511) to views in order to get GROUP_CONCAT as an aggregate function in views UI and uninstalled [views_merge_rows](https://drupal.org/project/views_merge_rows).
I think this is a better solution from a sql query performance point of view: views_merge_rows simply changes how data appear. Probably I was wrong in configuring something in it but I won't investigate any more.

Thanx all for reading...  ;-)